# AngularJS 1.6 : Object printed in Html is not visible (undefined) in controller function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

User clicks a file-upload button, which is defined in HTML as follows :

```
<input
            type="file"
            fileread
            style="display: none;">
```

After a file is chosen, this 'fileread' directive runs :

```
app.directive("fileread", [ function() {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.myCroppie = new Croppie();
                        console.log(scope.myCroppie); // <-- prints correctly                                                                               
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
} ]);
```

Please notice how scope.myCroppie is assigned a value.

In Html {{myCroppie}} is printed immediately. So no problem there.

Now; same page, a button and its ng-click function defined in the controller :

```
$scope.doStuff = function() {
    console.log($scope.myCroppie));
}
```

Console output is *undefined*.

I also tried "scope : true" in the directive, but with no success. The function in the controller still can't see $scope.myCroppie, which was created inside the directive's "link" function.

Is there a way to make this work ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working: https://jsfiddle.net/0aextp1e/
(also you should have tried to create this fiddle yourself to try to isolate the problem in the first place, before asking questions.)

But why it does not work? It should be working "unless" you have another scope in your code somewhere. Now, i do not know what's the rest of your code like, but that input is probably inside another `directive` that creates another child or isolated scope. That also explains how you get your `{{myCroppie}}` printed but can't access it in your controller. You probably put `{{myCroppie}}` inside the directive. Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/1rbt1zkg/1/

The directive in second plunker does transclusion, therefore has another isolated scope. Check if this is the case.

Comment: After posting here I actually created a plunker with the intention to edit this post. but the code in the plunker worked, but the actual code did not. I solved it by adding an attribute to the directive, " scope : { myCroppie : "=" }, and myCroppie is an object created in the controller. It worked that way. Still, I guess I should just delete this post, it wouldn't help anyone in the future. You're right, when I printed scope in link function, it showed a few levels of 'scopes' in console. Thank's for your help !